# Javascript check if HTML contains an item from an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a list of potential html classes in my javascript file

```
var html_list = ["blogrss",
"btnrss",
"buttonsrssfeed",
"copypasteblocker",
"facebook128x128",
"feedicon",
"iconrss",
"instagram128x128",
"jobwidget",
"pinterest128x128",
"pushnotification",
"rss128x128"]
```

Upon visiting a webpage i would like to iterate the array and if the webpage contains one of the elements a simple alert will show which html element the page contains.

Comment: what are these strings supposed to be? Classes? Ids? - what have you tried?

Comment: Please share your code for better understanding

Comment: Try google chrome extension TamperMonkey or FF extn GreaseMonkey and learn Userscripts to write in them

Comment: Are the values - ids of the elements or the tagnames ?

Comment: hi these are typical examples of spam  html classes used in certain webpages

Comment: [In the future, please make an attempt at figuring out the code yourself before posting](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to run a script that basically iterates through your list and checks the `DOM` to see if there's a match. Keep in mind that a `selector` can be a `tag`, `class`, `id`, etc... In your list, all selectors would be treated as a tag selector so you would need to provide the right selector and the rest will fall into place (`#id` or `.class-name` or `tagName`):

```
( () => {
    const elements = [
  "blogrss",
  "btnrss",
  "buttonsrssfeed",
  "copypasteblocker",
  "facebook128x128",
  "feedicon",
  "iconrss",
  "instagram128x128",
  "jobwidget",
  "pinterest128x128",
  "pushnotification",
  "rss128x128"
  ];
  const matchedElements = [];
  elements.forEach( (el) => {
    const match = document.querySelectorAll(el);
    if (match && match.length > 0) {
        matchedElements.push({ elementName: el, matches: match.length });
    }
  });
  alert(`Found ${matchedElements.length}`);
  console.log(matchedElements); // More detailed view of the matches
})();
```

Comment: thank you. These are examples of class names. Your solution looks good.

Comment: is there anyway to return to the name of the found element. Currently only found[Object object] is displayed?

Comment: You'll have to update your code and provide a JS Fiddle. The above code will display the element name since the array is an array of strings

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the jquery all selector
https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cheerio: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio

More specifically, check out the traversing section: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio#traversing

Answer (score 0):

you can use `document.getElementsByTagName("*")` to get all the elements, then simply use `classList` and `some` array method to determine if any elements have the class.

In the below function the `searchForClasses` function will return true or false depending on if there's a match.

```js
var html_list = [
  "testClass"
],
second_html_list = [
"banana"
]


function searchForClasses(classArray) {
  let class_included = false,
    elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("*"));
  for (let _class of classArray) {
    class_included = elements.some(ele => ele.classList.contains(_class));
    if (class_included) break;
  }
  return class_included;
}

console.log(searchForClasses(second_html_list)); // false
console.log(searchForClasses(html_list)); // true
```

```html
<div class="testClass"></div>
```